# How can I quickly enter a directory in helm-find-file when there is only one to select?

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

I'd like to quickly go down the file hierarchy and select the following dir when there is only one to select.
There would be two way of doing this :

- Stop showing the current and parent dir
- Select by default the first normal available file (preferred solution)

It there a way to configure that ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's exactly this feature. You can hit `C-<backspace>` to toggle it, or set the variable `helm-ff-auto-update-initial-value` to `t`.

> Documentation:
>
> Auto update when only one candidate directory is matched.
>
> Default value when starting ‘helm-find-files’ is nil because
>   it prevent using  to delete char backward and by the way
>   confuse beginners.
>
> For a better experience with ‘helm-find-files’ set this to non--nil
>   and use C- to toggle it.

Comment: Great, I wasnt using it, thanks for the tip. But is doesn't exactly solve my case. For example let's say there is a folder containing only a `src` folder. I wanna be able to quickly go down in that folder with `C-j`. But for now the file selected is the current folder and I have to type `C-n` twice before having `src` selected and being able to enter it with `C-j`. Maybe there is some customization I didn't find to enable it. But if not I'll just use the automatic update.

Comment: @montrivo Ah, I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question slightly. Supposedly, you should be able to edit the variable `helm-boring-file-regexp-list` and add the two strings `"\\.$" "\\.\\.$"`, but it's never worked for me.

Comment: See this [enhancement issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1863) and this
[bug issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/924).
Seems that it might be corrected in the future.

Comment: @montrivo No wonder! Oh well. Thanks for the links.